# Proof explanation to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}=\ln(2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, proof-explanation

So, I stumbled upon a proof [(here)](https://www.cglab.ca/%7Emorin/teaching/2804-f2019/resources/122.pdf) for the identity:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}=\ln(2)$$

However, I think there is something wrong with it, and would like some clarification. Here is a picture:

[image]

My problem is with $P_{2k}$ and $P_{2k+1}$. The only difference here is the endpoint, and also both goes over all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Both of them are also strictly positive as $(-1)^{2k}=1$. Did they do some kind of typo, and in that case, what? Should it be $(-1)^n$ instead of $(-1)^{2k}$? Or maybe it should only go over even/ odd numbers? Like so:

$$P_{2k}=\sum_{\substack{n=0, \\ \text{even}}}^{2k} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1} \qquad 
P_{2k+1}=\sum_{\substack{n=0, \\ \text{odd}}}^{2k+1} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$$

meaning that:

$$P_{2k}=\sum_{n=0}^{2k} (-1)^{2n} \frac{1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1} \qquad 
P_{2k+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{2k+1} (-1)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(2n+1)+1}x^{(2n+1)+1}$$

Can someone clarify this point? Thank you.

Comment: There is another method based on the fact that the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k}-\log n$ is convergent, [see](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant) The value of the limit is not essential.

Answer (score 2):

These are typos.  As it says, they should be partial sums of the series:
$$ \eqalign{P_{2k} &= \sum_{n=0}^{2k} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1} x^{n+1}\cr
P_{2k+1} &= \sum_{n=0}^{2k+1} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1} x^{n+1}\cr}$$